# Git commit reference over tags

Tags: git, continuous-integration, bamboo, git-tag

We use Git for source code versioning and Bamboo for continuous integration. Few projects in our organization do not tag the code in Git when they release a version to production. When quizzed about this, they say the commits in the specific build will tell the code that went into the production system.

My question is, is it sufficient to have the specific commits pointed to by a Bamboo build. Or we have other advantages of tagging which we do not get without tagging.

One thing I know is that the builds may not be retained in Bamboo (purging) and in the future, I may not have the snapshot of the source code that was in production at some point in time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tags are nothing more than easy to understand names given to specific commits. The main advantage in using them I can think of is that it makes the git repository self-descriptive. You don't have to juggle between git and bamboo to get a correct picture of what version is which. This is especially important if your bamboo server is down (e.g., for scheduled maintenance) or if you ever want to switch to a different CI system.

Answer (score 1):

So I'll answer this a little farther then tags.

But as to your original question, tags are an immutable reference to a specific time in a commit. As Mureinik has stated, a tag is just an easy reference to a specific hash in your git repository.

But for you second point, Bamboo has a built in Expiry, which also has an exception field.  Any release can be labeled as such and be tagged in the exception list of the expiry (the exception list can be regex i.e. release/1.0.0 matches release.*)